# how to play the output file of JM encoder?

Tags: video, video-encoding, encoder

i have encoded a video sequence via JM software and the output is with the format *.264  which software do i need to to see this file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode it first. The decoder will generate a .yuv file which you will be able to see.
Note the quality of this video depends on the encoder configurations that you have used.